# invalid command 'npm run build' when running it from setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, distutils

I am trying to build the Javascript end of my app using `npm run build` via the `setup.py` config file. I am using the `build` class from `distutils` as suggested elsewhere, but I am getting an error when I run `pip install .`

```
from setuptools import setup
from distutils.command.build import build
import json
import os

class javascript_build(build):
    def run(self):
        self.run_command("npm run build")
        build.run(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup(
        cmdclass={'build': javascript_build},
         )
```

Does anyone know why is this happening?

```
 running npm run build
 error: invalid command 'npm run build'
 ----------------------------------------
 ERROR: Failed building wheel for chemiscope
```

EDIT 1: So it seems that instead of running `npm run build`, it is running `python setup.py npm run build`. So my question changes a little to how do I exactly force `distutils` to run `npm run build`?

Comment: Have you installed `nodejs` in the app before? `npm` would not run until the system where you want to install has `nodejs` runtime.

Comment: Yes, I can normally run `npm run build` from the command line. Only when I try to do it via the `setup.py` file, does it produce this invalid command thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.run_command("xxx")` doesn't run a program — it calls another `distutils`/`setuptools` subcommand; something like calling `python setup.py xxx` but from the same process, not via the command line. So you can do `self.run_command("sdist")` but not `self.run_command("npm")`.

In your case you need `os.system("npm run build")` or `subprocess.call("npm run build")`.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to get this working by using `subprocess.check_output()` as shown below. I am not sure if this is ideal, but it does the job.

```
from setuptools import setup
from distutils.command.build import build
from distutils import log
import subprocess
import json
import os

class javascript_build(build):
    def run(self):
        log.info("running npm run build")
        subprocess.check_output(['npm', 'run', 'build'], shell=True)
        build.run(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup(
        cmdclass={
            'build': javascript_build,
            },
    )
```